# ASP.NET using Window Authentication by matching a userid from SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

Can you guy send me a good example that they will verify my userid which it from window login workstation and match a list of userid in table in SQL Server? I am using IIS and they are both in same server but different machine. If my userid is not match one of those userid in table then it automatic prevent me from going in specific website. I do not want login or form. I just want automatic detect my userid before allow me to enter website.

Answer (score 0):

What authentication mechanism are you using on the website? Forms? Integrated? Certificate mapping?

In the end, the authentication mechanism will generate a cookie which you can reference in code via HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.

Your job is to figure out which authentication mechanism you are using and understand what the Identity.Name value is being generated by, since the authentication mechanism controls this and to synchronize the value in your user's table with this value. It does not necessarily need to be the primary key of the user's table; in fact security is slightly improved if you do not expose the primary key of the user's table at all. Any unique key will do; in general I use Guids because I can generate them independently and their sequence is (generally) not predictable.

Comment: I am using Window Authentication during Page_Load. I use "string user = Page.User.Identity.Name;" then I want to use loop to check each value in userID column to match user. If it match then allow me to go in website. If not, then it deny with proper website message that I do not have authorization to access.